# dotnet cake fails with error: Unable to find package

Tags: docker, nuget

I am trying to run dotnet cake on my solution inside a build server (docker container)

I keep getting the error:

```
/app # dotnet cake
Error: Unable to find package 'Cake.My'. Existing packages must be restored before performing an install or update.
```

I have a the nupkg file in a folder at the same level as the nuget config:

```
app # ls -lah
total 192K   
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Jun 28 20:34 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Jun 28 20:34 ..
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root        4.0K Jun 28 20:07 .nuget
drwxr-xr-x    6 root     root        4.0K Jun 28 20:33 cake2
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root         527 Jun 28 20:33 nuget.config
```

Inside the cake2 folder I have the following:

```
/app/cake2 # ls -lah
total 88K    
drwxr-xr-x    6 root     root        4.0K Jun 28 20:33 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        4.0K Jun 28 20:34 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       50.9K Jun 28 19:25 Cake.My.2.0.0.nupkg
```

And this is what my nuget.config looks like:

```
/app # cat nuget.config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="packages" />
  </config>
  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="LocalPackages" value="./cake2" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```